# c# class INotifyPropertyChanged or class with events

Tags: c#

I don't understand exactly what is the difference if I derive my objects from `INotifyPropertyChanged` like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41817/Implementing-INotifyPropertyChanged) article.

Or make the class from the beginning "with events" by declaring some `EventHandler` and just rise it when need.

Thanks for clarifications,

Comment: Could you add an example? Its unclear what you mean by making a "class from the beginning with events"

Comment: The interface just forces you to create an event with a well-known name, it must be PropertyChanged.  Which matters to code that otherwise knows absolutely nothing about your class.  .NET Framework code that was written 7 years ago, it can't know anything about the code you write today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is used to notify clients,
>   typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.

So if you want to use the class properties in `binding` you should inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Otherwise you have to make the notifying mechanism manually.

Answer (score 1):

Deriving from `INotifyPropertyChanged` allows client's to subscribe to the change event without knowing the details of your class.

If you use some other custom event for changing they cannot do this, and thus will not receive notifications of data changing.

Note, it is common to define an abstract class with the common parts of your `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation (the event, a protected `OnPropertyChanged` talking just the property name) to save repeating the same implementation across multiple types.